Adding a new custom property to a WPF element
So much like a Header is a property of a TreeViewItem, I am trying to add another property that I can reference for my code.
I started looking into DependencyProperty, but I have a feeling this is the wrong direction, as well as making a simple extension to try and set the property I am looking for.
The little snippet that I'm trying to get to work looks a little like this:
public bool AddNewTreeviewChild(ItemCollection selectedTreeView, TreeViewItem selectedItem)
{
    if (selectedTreeView.Contains(selectedItem))
    {
        var newChild = new TreeViewItemExtension();
        newChild.Header = NewItem.Text;
        newChild.TreeViewType = DesignateChildType();
        selectedItem.Items.Add(newChild);
    }

    foreach (TreeViewItem item in selectedTreeView)
    {
        if (AddNewTreeviewChild(item.Items, selectedItem))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

The dependency Property way I tried:
public static readonly DependencyProperty TreeViewTypeProp = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "TreeViewType",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(TreeViewItem),
        new PropertyMetadata("Root")
        );

public string TreeViewType
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(TreeViewTypeProp); }
    set { SetValue(TreeViewTypeProp, value); }
}

However, this still makes the TreeViewType inaccessible or unsable in the above example, thus not compiling or running.
I also attempted doing an extension with a simple:
   public class TreeViewItemExtension : TreeViewItem
    {
        public string TreeViewType { get; set; }

        public TreeViewItemExtension ()
        {
            
        }
    }

But when looking at newly added items, the TreeViewType is missing. I tried casting and renaming various TreeViewItems into TreeViewItemExtension, but had no luck. What am I missing?
Edit: Implementing the solution BigBoss provided below, ran into a new problem. As I am testing these things, I have a function for feeding back info for me, in regard to the TreeView items/parents. The below section, does not seem to return an attached property
public string GetTreeviewParent(TreeViewItem item)
{
    DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(item);
    string parentPath = ">";
    while (!(parent is TreeView))
    {
        parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);

        if (parent != null)
        {
            ItemsControl parentItem = parent as ItemsControl;
            TreeViewItem parentName = parentItem as TreeViewItem;
            if (parentName != null)
            {
                parentPath = ">" + parentName.Header.ToString() + parentPath;
                MessageBox.Show(TreeViewType.GetTreeViewType(parent));
            }
        }
    }

    return parentPath;
}

This just returns an empty string, however, with the below code, I can confirm that the newChild has the TreeViewType property, and it is TestChild, before being written to the tree.
        var newChild = new TreeViewItem();
        newChild.Header = NewItem.Text;
        TreeViewType.SetTreeViewType(newChild, "TestChild");
        MessageBox.Show(TreeViewType.GetTreeViewType(newChild));
        selectedItem.Items.Add(newChild);

what have I missed?
Edit 2: The obvious. I was checking the parent, and not the item itself. So the syntax above, for when I am displaying the messagebox, should've been MessageBox.Show(TreeViewType.GetTreeViewType(item));
instead of
MessageBox.Show(TreeViewType.GetTreeViewType(parent));
Everything is now working fine like expected now, and that was just an oversight on my end.

I think attached properties will do the trick.
First define an attached property:
public class TreeViewType
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TreeViewTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "TreeViewType", 
        typeof(string), 
        typeof(TreeViewItem), 
        new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public static string GetTreeViewType(DependencyObject target) => (string)target.GetValue(TreeViewTypeProperty);
    public static void SetTreeViewType(DependencyObject target, string value) => target.SetValue(TreeViewTypeProperty, value);
}

You can then set the TreeViewType for individual TreeViewItems in code:
TreeViewType.SetTreeViewType(item, "type1");

And get the TreeViewType like:
string type = TreeViewType.GetTreeViewType(item);

Edit:
Your AddNewTreeviewChild method would look like this:
public bool AddNewTreeviewChild(ItemCollection selectedTreeView, TreeViewItem selectedItem)
  {
      if (selectedTreeView.Contains(selectedItem))
      {
          var newChild = new TreeViewItem();
          newChild.Header = NewItem.Text;
          TreeViewType.SetTreeViewType(newChild, DesignateChildType());
          selectedItem.Items.Add(newChild);
      }

      foreach (TreeViewItem item in selectedTreeView)
      {
          if (AddNewTreeviewChild(item.Items, selectedItem))
          {
              return true;
          }
      }

      return false;
  }


If I'm understanding this correct, the "Item" in TreeViewType.SetTreeViewType(item, "type1"); refers to the TreeViewItem I'm trying to assign the "type1" to?
If I was to change the SetTreeViewType method to not include the "DependencyObject target" then it would not result in a simple string assignment to my custom property?

@VladSD Yes, the item is the specific TreeViewItem you're assigning "type1" to. I've edited my answer to include the AddNewTreeviewChild method. I'm not sure what you mean by not including the DependencyObject target. If you remove the DependencyObject target, you cannot call target.SetValue inside the SetTreeViewType method.

That makes a bit more sense, thank you. Appreciate the help :) As someone still learning these things, it helps a lot.

Having an issue getting the value back, after the new child is added to the tree. Updating original post

@VladSD Did you set the TreeViewType to the parent TreeViewItem? In the AddNewTreeviewChild method, you add newChild to selectedItem, check if you actually set TreeViewType to that selectedItem. Maybe you have a "root" TreeViewItem defined that you never set TreeViewType to.
